# Adding link_to tag in autocomplete results in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to add link to show page in autocomplete results. But its not working. I post my code below. But i tried to check whether my jquery is getting executed with an alert box. it works fine. But when i tried to add css for some div using jquery I cant.

//application.js

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var key = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("search-display").innerHTML = "";
        }
        if(key.length == 0){
            document.getElementById("search-display").innerHTML = "No results found";
        }
        for( var i=0; i < key.length; i++){
            var display = key[i].firstname + "&nbsp&nbsp" + key[i].mobilenumber + 
               "\n" <%= link_to 'show', contact_path(@contact) %>;   //this line is not working

            document.getElementById("search-display").innerHTML += display;

            $(document).ready(function(){
                // alert("hello");
                **$("#search-display").css('background','white');** //this line is not getting executed 
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please state exactly what is not working. Simply stating "it's not working" makes it hard to help you. Also, it might be nice to explain what you tried to solve the problem so far and why that did not work.

Comment: thanks for your tip. i will edit my question now.

Comment: Seems like you simply have a wrong selector, should be $('#search-display')

Comment: omgggggg silly mistake rite????thanks a lott @rubish

Comment: But my question was wrong. now i heve edited it. link_to is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript is running on the client browser.
It doesn't know anything about Ruby on Rails and doesn't have any idea what the `link_to` stuff is about.

The approach you should use in these cases is:

1. A link that that calls javascript
2. Any required javascript needed at that point (disabling a link or a search button is a frequent action here) is done as needed and then rails is called with a GET
3. Receive any response from the rails server in JSON
4. Use the JSON info (sometimes) to then update the screen further. for example remove checkboxes or populate a dropdown list of suggestions (as needed in your case).

Which you do when depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript is running on the client machine. It does not have access to Rails helpers. You can build the full URL on the server side ( in your controller ) and send it in the JSON response.